# Making sure a final field is initialized in Java

Tags: java, final

I extend a class with multiple constructors. I add a final field in my subclass which ofcourse needs to be initialized in my own constructors.

The problem is I don't want to re-implement (most) of the constructors of the superclass, so I would like to do something like this:

```
public myConstructor(Object... params){
    super(params);
    try{
        this.finalField = "backup value";
    }
    catch(someException e){

    }
}
```

Is this possible in some way or the other?

***edit***:
I realized this scenario will never happen, because the superclass constructor will never call my own constructor.

Comment: Not clear.  Are you saying you don't want to initialize a final field in the same class that declares it?  That's not permitted.

Comment: Do you want to re-initialize a **final** field in the subclass? That's not legal either.

Comment: @JudgeMental I'm saying that in some constructors I am not certain whether a final field is initialized or not. If it's not, I would like to initialize it.

Comment: @dtech: initialize where you declared it.

Comment: @iozee OP clearly said that "_I add a final field in my subclass_"

Comment: The compiler will not allow you to have a final field that's not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have all your constructors call one single constructor that sets the final field.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify process of object initialization, usually I use the following solutions:

- You could create a static-factory method which will be create object (and throw exceptions if needed) instead of constructors and provide common initialization functionality in reusable private method.
- Also you could use Builder-pattern instead of multiple constructors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern